# how to define a route to pass two values in a rest url, and use it. Ruby on rails 2.3.11

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In Ruby on rails, I need to make a ajax call to a method and pass two values, latitude and longitude. How do I define such a route in route.rb?

Once the route is defined how do I make this Ajax call from the JavaScript method and update a Div?

Thanks
Shaunak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify that there are two variables for a restful route. You an just include it in the route.

For example:

```
<%= link_to @post.name, post_path(@post, :anchor => @post.name)%>
```

That will create a anchor link. Pass any other parameter as key => value pairs.

Comment: Here is My Scenario: I am trying to find out elevation at mouse click on map. So i need to make my ajax call from the javascript and update a div by passing lat long. Can you show how i can do that? Thanks